# 'Value out of range' error in word file when using range search using C#

Tags: c#, word-interop

I use below code which is very good at copy and paste in front page. But when applying documents with 2 or more pages the error code 'Value out of range' . Below is my code. Please help, I'm just learning for the first time!!

```
for (int i = 1; i < docs.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
{
    progressBar1.Value = i;
    string a = docs.Paragraphs[i].Range.Text.ToString();
    string b = "SINH HOẠT DƯỚI CỜ";
    if (string.Compare(a.Trim(), b.Trim(), true) == 0)// kiểm tra dòng này có thuộc tiêu đề kia không
    {
        var d1 = docs.Content.Paragraphs[i].Range;// chọn phạm vi khi điều kiện hợp lệ
        Range d2 = docs.Content;// chọn phạm vi cuối cùng
        d1.Find.Execute(b);// tìm kiếm tên trong phạm vi đó
        d2.Find.Execute("- Phương pháp vấn đáp, động não, thực hành, thảo luận nhóm.");
        Range range1 = docs.Range(d1.Start, d2.End);// System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Value out of range'
        range1.Copy();
        rtbsoanthao.Paste();
    }
}
```

Comment: On which line does the error message say this occurrs?

Comment: Why is this tagged "javascript" ?

Comment: You are using index `i` for indexing into `docs.Paragraphs` as well as `docs.Content.Paragraphs` (when assigning to d1). Are those guaranteed to be the same size?

Comment: Line error Range range1 = docs.Range(d1.Start, d2.End); //
Thank you Fildor!!! I'll try it out. Respectfully yours

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Fildor I figured out the answer. Thank you very much. Of course I didn't notice the index in the last line range. Already my code. It works very well. Copy as required by a word file at your own discretion.

```
for (int i = 1; i < docs.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
                {
                    progressBar1.Value = i;                   
                    string a = "tập đọc";
                    string b = docs.Paragraphs[i].Range.Text.ToString();
                    if (string.Compare(a.Trim(), b.Trim(), true) == 0)// kiểm tra dòng này có thuộc tiêu đề kia không
                    {                      
                        for (int j = i; j < docs.Paragraphs.Count; j++)
                        {
                            string c = "---------------------------------------------------- ";
                            string d = docs.Paragraphs[j].Range.Text.ToString();
                            if (string.Compare(c.Trim(), d.Trim(), true) == 0)
                            {
                                Range d1 = docs.Content.Paragraphs[i].Range;
                                Range d2 = docs.Content.Paragraphs[j].Range;
                                d1.Find.Execute(a);
                                d2.Find.Execute(c);
                                Range range1 = docs.Range(d1.Start, d2.End);
                                range1.Copy();
                                rtbsoanthao.Paste();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }                
                }
```